# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file error while calling web service

Tags: java, web-services

I am getting following error while using a web service.

500 Internal Server Error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.3.0)].util.OC4JSecureClassLoader.defineClassEntry(OC4JSecureClassLoader.java:172)
    at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.3.0)].naming.ContextClassLoader.defineClass(ContextClassLoader.java:1179)
    at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.3.0)].naming.ContextClassLoader.defineClass(ContextClassLoader.java:1065)
    at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.3.0)].naming.ContextClassLoader.findClass(ContextClassLoader.java:404)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.3.0)].naming.ContextClassLoader.loadClass(ContextClassLoader.java:143)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:299)
    at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.3.0)].naming.ContextClassLoader.loadClass(ContextClassLoader.java:143)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:299)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.JavaRpcWebService.init(JavaRpcWebService.java:85)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:258)
    at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.3.0)].server.http.HttpApplication.loadServlet(HttpApplication.java:2358)
    at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.3.0)].server.http.HttpApplication.findServlet(HttpApplication.java:4800)
    at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.3.0)].server.http.HttpApplication.getRequestDispatcher(HttpApplication.java:2826)
    at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.3.0)].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.processRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:666)
    at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.3.0)].server.http.AJPRequestHandler.run(AJPRequestHandler.java:231)
    at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.3.0)].server.http.AJPRequestHandler.run(AJPRequestHandler.java:136)
    at com.evermind[Oracle Application Server Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.2.3.0)].util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor.java:192)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

I have seen earlier posts also but couldn't find any solution for this. The source files are present on a different server and the web service is deployed on different server. Can anyone help to find out what is causing the issue ?

Comment: Your source files (or jars you use) were compiled with a higher javac version than what you use to run your server with.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to lower `java version` on your system. Means your `jar` or `java` file that you are importing in your project is compiled on higher version of java.

Answer (score 0):

Your source files (or jars you use) were compiled with a higher `javac` version than what you use to run your server with.

Possible solutions: either recompile your sources targeting the java version you run your server with or install the required new java version on your server and run your webapp with that.